# Use object variable in base.html of Django

Tags: django

I come from Ruby on Rails and I am trying to learn Django. There are multiple things that puzzle me when it comes to how to solve simple things. I have a sidebar in which I would like to have a link to a random item.

My first thought was to use:

```
<a href="{% url 'headline_detail' Headline.objects.order_by('?')[0].id %}">Random headline</a>
```

Although it works perfectly fine to run `Headline.objects.order_by('?')[0].id` in the shell, this causes an error in Django:

```
Could not parse the remainder: '('?')[0].id' from 'Headline.objects.order_by('?')[0].id'
```

which I find very weird since 'Headline.objects.order_by('?')[0].id' creates a number (id) and if I put the same number in as

```
<a href="{% url 'headline_detail' 123 %}">Random headline</a>
```

it works perfectly fine.

Another option would be to create this previously in the template, like

```
{% rand_id = Headline.objects.order_by('?')[0].id %}
<a href="{% url 'headline_detail' Headline.objects.order_by('?')[0].id %}">Random headline</a>
```

which is I would hotfix it in Rails - but this doesn't work. The third option (which is better than the 2nd) is to put the variable in the view. However, this is not really viable since this code is in the sidebar and I cannot pass this in every view (DRY!).

So, I figure out I should use **context templates**, which I - after reading up on it find overly complicated for something as simple as this.

Is there really no good, simple way to solve this problem? Or am I "thinking too much rails"?

Comment: Django template engine is intentionally kept simple to prevent embedding too much business logic into templates. The usual recommendation is to compute the `Headline` instance in the view and pass it as a separate context variable. You can have a look at `jinja2` engine which is more capable.

Comment: I have worked more with Flask (jinja) which I found way easier to get around but I need to learn Django for my CV basically. I can't use the Headline instance in the view as it is supposed to be used globally (it's in a sidebar)

Comment: You know Django can use jinja2 as an alternative template engine but I understand your willingness to learn the built-in engine too. You can write a context processor to make it available to all templates, regardless of the view.

Comment: Jinja2 isn't going to work either. This reference to "Headline" is an imported class. It won't work if you just open the shell and type Headline.objects..... The same applies to a template.

Comment: I had the same issue when starting with Django: templates can extend other (base)templates but context data is created in each view individually. I finally used context templates as you already mention yourself. Pretty complex but still the easiest way I think.

Comment: Maybe a Django expert could comment on the idea to use Class based view to "inherit" context parts like the template "extends". This is not at all thought through to the end though. I just remember thinking about it a while ago but at that time too much in a Django beginner situation

Comment: Thanks for all the input. I guess I have to look into context templates for this. After all, I do this to learn Django, but I really thought it would be a simpler solution for something so common. I am not too impressed by Django so far but I may be looking at it from a wrong (Rails) perspective.

Comment: Note that it's "context processors", not context templates and they are not complex at all. Class based views don't bring anything new as far as context variables are concerned.

Answer (score 0):

In your case a custom template tag would be just fine.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags

```py
from django import template
from django.utils.html import format_html

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def random_headline_link():
    random_headline = Headline.objects.order_by('?')[0]
    headline_url = reverse('headline_detail', args=[random_headline.id,])
    return format_html('<a href="{url}">Random headline</a>', url=headline_url)
```

```html
{% random_headline_link %}
<!-- the rest is not needed anymore, as it is all coupled together in the templatetag -->
```

Or if you only like/need the URL, you could use the following templatetag code.

```py
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def random_headline_url():
    random_headline = Headline.objects.order_by('?')[0]
    return reverse('headline_detail', args=[random_headline.id,])
```

```html
<a href="{% random_headline_url %}">Random headline</a>
```